# I am trying to run my latex file but I end up getting error with \medspace

Tags: pdftex

I get the following error when I typeset my latex (i.e. `.tex`) file.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \medspace already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                    

l.11957
\newcommand{\medspace}{\kern .22222em }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Without a full minimal code, what can we say?

Comment: Have you tried `\renewcommand{\medspace}{\kern .22222em }`? (Hint: Since `\medspace` is already defined, you can't define it using `\newcommand`; you have to re-define it via `\renewcommand`.)

Comment: I tried it but still shows the same error.

Comment: @Mico `\medspace` is not defined by the LaTeX kernel; did you mean `\medskip`?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, on line 11957 the command `\newcommand` should define `\medspace`, but it complains that it is already defined. What's your problem with that?

Answer (score 2):

The command `\medspace` is defined by `amsmath`. It's a bad idea to redefine it. Besides, used in text mode it produces a space of 0.2222em, essentially the same as you'd like to define it

```
% amsmath.sty, lines 153-154
\renewcommand{\:}{\tmspace+\medmuskip{.2222em}}
\let\medspace\:
```